# Multiple site collection with multiple URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, 2016

I am trying to configure multiple site collection for one web application,

Is it possible to set each site collection with its URL, for example

```
Site collection URL                           Public URL

http://webapplication/stiecollection1          http://aasharia.com
http://webapplication/stiecollection2          http://kumar.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, looks like path based site collection will be a good fit for you.

Every site collection in sharepoint has unique urls, you can create multiple site collections in a web applications. When you create the web application  then 1st will be root site collection followed by path. I.e.

```
Http://webapplication.com/
Http://webapplication.com/sites/sitecollection1
Http://webapplication.com/sites/sitecollection2
Http://webapplication.com/sites/sitecollection3
```

But if you don't want path "/sites/sitecollection1" in your URL then you have to create host name site collection.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263094.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can created host named site collections.
Refer MSDN for more details - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it's possible.
We can configure SharePoint Alternate Access Mappings to make host named site collection url.
Check the blog below for detailed message:

[SharePoint AAM](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-alternate-access-mappings-host-named-site-collections-and-ssl)